# Which layout to use and how to achieve the following?

Tags: android, layout

I have been struggling to figure out which layout to use and how to achieve what I am looking for. I've tried gridlayouts, linear and relative layouts as well as scroll views in many different combinations. What I want is something like Google now.

I have two buttons to launch the two modes in my app. I have an imagebutton in the top right which they press for more information and when they do so a text view slides out. I have made the layout work, and to overlay the imagebutton on my mode buttons I require a relative layout. However my problem comes from trying to optimise for different screen sizes. I would like it to centre the buttons to rest a quarter of the way down and the layout to pop out underneath towards the half way mark. For the bottom button I want it three quarters of the way down with a text view that drops down towards the bottom. If there isn't sufficient space to fit everything I want a scroll view for when the text views appear, but otherwise it should fit comfortably and not require scrolling.

How do I do this? Two nested relative layouts within a linearlayout, both with equal weight? Then some how I need to address that if the length of the height (taking in account orientation) does not allow it to fit, adapt it so the buttons are closer and scrollable.

Comment: I have read all the android guidelines. I'm still confused.

Comment: Its not just you.  The layout stuff is confusing.

Comment: can you show some drawing or somthing, how it should look like?

Answer (score 1):

You can use sepperate res/layout folders for different screen sizes just like with drawables, examples: layout-small, layout-large etc.
More explained here http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html#TaskUseWrapMatchPar

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As I mentioned I've read these guidelines thoroughly. Just as an FYI, the new smallestWidth guidelines are preferred to small, large etc.